# Why does mremap on two consecutive shared memory regions result in SIGBUS?

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

For context: I am implementing an x86 linux emulator and am trying to wrap my head around understanding what the `mremap` syscall does. The only case that currently does not make much sense to me is the case where `old_len` is set to `0`.

As far as i understand the docs this can be used to make a new mapping of an already mapped shared memory area, effectively creating a second virtual address mapping to the same physical memory. (I.e. it would be possible to access the same physical memory via the two different virtual address ranges)

So far so good. This works as expected when i try it. However, when there are two consecutive memory regions, e.g., 0xf1000..0xf4000 and 0xf4000..0xf7000 this results in a SIGBUS when writing across the boundary of the regions (after mremapping). See the example below:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    char* mapping = mmap((void *) 0xf1000, 0x3000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    char* mapping2 = mmap((void *) 0xf4000, 0x3000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    char* mapping3 = mremap((void *) 0xf3000, 0x0, 0x3000, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, 0xf9000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 0x3000; ++i) mapping3[i] = 'A';
    printf("%c\n", mapping[0x2000]);
    printf("Mapping pointer: %p\n", mapping);
    printf("Mapping2 pointer: %p\n", mapping2);
    printf("Mapping3 pointer: %p\n", mapping3);
    return 0;
}
```

If the loop only iterates over the first 0x1000 characters, then the changes are reflected in `mapping` as i would expect.

Why does this result in a SIGBUS and why does the call to mremap not fail, if this is not allowed?

Comment: 0xf3000 does not refer to an existing mapping.

Comment: @stark It actually does.  This is legal in the case where `MAP_PRIVATE` and not this `old_size == 0` trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after looking into this, it appears you cannot do this `mremap` across maps thing with `MAP_SHARED` the way you can with `MAP_PRIVATE`.

If you change the `mmap` calls to use MAP_PRIVATE, you hit [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/mremap.c#L765) error:

```
    if (!old_len && !(vma->vm_flags & (VM_SHARED | VM_MAYSHARE))) {
        pr_warn_once("%s (%d): attempted to duplicate a private mapping with mremap.  This is not supported.\n", current->comm, current->pid);
        return ERR_PTR(-EINVAL);
    }
```

... which I can actually verify as that message appeared in `dmesg`:

```
[ 3566.135161] a.out (4234): attempted to duplicate a private mapping with mremap.  This is not supported.
```

If you change, the `mremap` call to not do the `old_len == 0` trick:

```
char* mapping3 = mremap((void *) 0xf3000, 0x3000, 0x3000, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, 0xf9000);
```

... you will get `errno` of `EFAULT` (bad address).  This appears to get caught [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/mremap.c#L775):

```
    /* We can't remap across vm area boundaries */
    if (old_len > vma->vm_end - addr)
        return ERR_PTR(-EFAULT);
```

As you can see, the `old_len == 0` will skip this statement (assuming intentionally).

When using `MAP_SHARED`, this is managed by the `shmem` system which appears to operate a bit differently in terms of map boundaries.  However, I could not pinpoint exactly where in the source this is decided.   I think this is related to the fact that `MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS` mappings [cannot grow](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-mm/msg214704.html).  So you hit the same error if you were to grow a `MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS` mapping.  It will silently succeed, but then throw a bus error when you read/write into the newly allocated section.

Your bus error occurs when you try to write into the first page of what is originally defined as `mapping2`.  So it would seem, this is just something you cannot do.  As it stands, it would be better to think of `MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS` mappings as distinct units when using `mremap`.

Comment: So basically this behavior is a bug (when looking at the two bugs in the bugtracker) and no one cared to fix it yet because it is rarely used?

Comment: Doing the mremap with `MAP_PRIVATE` and without the `old_len == 0` trick also seems to work which is weird. Imho the whole syscall seems to be a bit lacking compared to the rest. It tries to do a lot of things at once and it is not clearly specified in the  docs what it is supposed to do in each special case and what you are not allowed.

Comment: @MarkG Yeah, it would seem that on the surface, they just have a similar API while, under the hood, they use 2 different systems.  I believe `MAP_SHARED` can grow in the case of not using `MAP_ANONYMOUS` (and obviously providing a file backing), but having experimented with it for this answer, I believe the `old_len == 0` trick still did not work, but it sort of removes the need for it as there is now a file backing.  I wonder if you had a real-world use case for this that maybe the file backing solves?

Comment: I don't have any use cases here since i am trying to re-implement the actual mremap call for my emulator. I was trying to be true to the specification which is kind of hard, since the call does not fail and instead later produces issues when accessing the memory. I will just opt for failing the call in this case i guess. I doubt anyone actually uses this functionality, since the bug from 2007 or so is still not resolved.